# Head up notifications are not showing in react android

Tags: react-native, react-android

I’m trying to listen for data messages. At the moment, I’ve implemented the Headless JS functionality but I’m not receiving the notification on these two cases (background and closed). But notification receiving when the app in the foreground, but not showing the head up notification it always goes to notification tray.

```
{
 “data”: {
 “title”: “title”,
 “body”: “body”,
},
 “priority”: “high”,
 “to”: “eu…otVKCbii1-l”
}
```

I'm Using this tutorial 
https://medium.com/@bsnair220/thanks-for-the-tutorial-29a3dbce6501